# SetInterval using linkObj

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

With this code I expect to see a 'yo' added to the console every second while I'm hovering over .cell-top. But I get one 'yo' and that's it.

```
function cellUp(linkObj) {
    console.log('yo');
}
$(".cell-top").hover(function() {
    setInterval(cellUp($(this)), 1000);
});
```

Any idea what I can do to get my expected results?

PS. I'm using linkObj to get $(this) in a function within cellDown, I didn't include the function because that's unrelated to the issue I'm having. I did include the linkObj because I figured it may be part of the issue.

Comment: What is actually `linkObj` ? :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: `cellUp($(this))`

Comment: @CrazyTrain I know that, but stated in the Q title sounds like the OP is confusing some things ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var interval;
function cellUp(linkObj) {
    console.log(linkObj);
}
$(".cell-top").hover(function() {
    var self = this;
    interval = setInterval(function(){cellUp($(self))}, 1000);
},function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
});
```

Comment: @veinmelter the problem is that in your code, you're **calling** "cellUp" and passing the **result** of that call, which results in nothing happening. You have to pass a function.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using jQuery, you can use `$.proxy`.

```
$(".cell-top").hover(function() {
    setInterval($.proxy(cellUp, null, $(this)), 1000);
});
```

Comment: this is best answer here +1 but maybe you should clear interval, even OP doesn't tell about it

Comment: Yeah, I put this in, works great. I didn't mention clear interval, no. I figured I'd be able to figure that out. Could you show how I might clear interval here? It's not working as a handler out on the hover function.

Comment: @veinmelter: roasted gave a more complete solution. You should check that out, and you may want to "accept" that one.

Comment: Yeah, after some further investigation I agree

Comment: Though you rule for introducing me to $.proxy()